# $scope variable come back to me as $scope.$$v

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a factory that returns an object from $http.get

```
app.factory( 'myFactory', function($http) {
  return {
    get: function() {
        return $http.get('/data').success(function(data) {
          return data
        })
    }
  }
})
```

then

```
$scope.listings = myFactory.get()
```

In index.html, I use ng-repeat on **listings.data** and **there is no problem finding each object.**

Then from a directive I call .getListings() that's in my controller and in the Chrome Javascript console $scope.listings =

```
Object {then: function, success: function, error: function, $$v: Object}
```

Why can't I just use this?

```
$scope.listings.data
```

And is it ok to use this?

```
$scope.listings.$$v.data
```

What is $$v?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making little mistake in your code with get in service you return a promise object which will be filled when you sucessfully complete response from the server so kindly modify your code below to make it working.

```
app.factory( 'myFactory', function($http) {
  return {
    get: function() {
        return $http.get('/data')
    }
  }
})


myFactory.get().then(function(data){
$scope.listings=data;
});
```